# h1 and h4 weirdly sticking together in one line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Normally two the two headings must appear on separate lines, but they stick together and even `<br>` doesn't do anything here! I wonder why that is happening, I am following a tutorial on youtube and doing exactly what I was told I get this result which is different from what tutor shows, h1 and h4 being on two lines centered.

```css
.hero {
  height: 40vh;
  background: url(../assets/artificial-leather-material.jpg) center/cover no-repeat;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  border-radius: var(--borderRadius);
  position: relative;

}

.hero-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
}

.hero-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
/*   color: white; */
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1.38rem;
  font-family: var(--headingFont);
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  letter-spacing: var(--letterSpacing);
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 3.052rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.441rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.953rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.563rem;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<main class="page">
     <!-- header -->
     <header class="hero">
     <div class="hero-container">
       <div class="hero-text">
         <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
         <h4>nonsense at its finest</h4>
       </div>           
     </div>
    </header>
   </main>
```

Comment: What do you think `display: flex` means?

Comment: [You shouldn't put h1 and h4 next to each other in the first place](https://www.nomensa.com/blog/how-structure-headings-web-accessibility)

Comment: It centers the element when used with align-items and justify-content, or at least that's what I learned @Quentin

Answer (score 2):

It is because `.hero-text` uses flexbox layout and its default behavior is to stack its children along x axis.

You can change it with `flex-direction: column` in order to stack the elements along vertical axis.

```
.hero-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

But it takes time to understand flexbox, so in case you would find it confusing, you can simple take all the `.hero-text` definitions away, which will cause that it will act like default block element (where block elements are stacking below each other)... And then, if you want to make text centered, you can do it in an easier way using `text-align: center`.

```
.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
}
```